# DAX constant vs. reference: constant works, reference doesn't

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a table where I would like to calculate the sum of the hours in the first month of the data.
I have a calculated field that dynamically finds the min. month in the table:

`MinMonth:=CALCULATE(MONTH(MIN([Month])))`

This outputs 1, 2, ..., 12

I then have a field that calculates the sum. If i type a static number

`CALCULATE(SUM([Hours]);[Month]=1)`

It works. But if I type a reference to the calculated field:

`CALCULATE(SUM([Hours]);[MonthNo]=[MinMonth])`

It doesn't. Even if I create a cell:

`MinMonthTest:=1`

And reference it, it doesn't work. Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a measure in a simple boolean filter. The easiest workaround is to pre-calculated it as a static variable.

```
Measure =
VAR MinMonth = [MinMonth]
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Hours] ); [Month] = MinMonth )
```

The other option is to use a `FILTER` argument:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Hours] ),
    FILTER ( VALUES ( [Month] ), [Month] = [MinMonth] )
)
```

These still may not return what you expect though since `[MinMonth]` will be evaluated within the filter context it is called in and it's not entirely clear if that's what you want or not. If not, then you probably want something more like this to ignore that evaluation context:

```
MinMonth := CALCULATE ( MONTH ( MIN ( [Month] ) ), ALL ( TableName ) )
```